# Segment count for index in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm in the process of optimizing old indices in my ElasticSearch cluster. Our data is time based so our older indices are only searched and never written.

I've read merging to a single segment is ideal for this sort of index and have done this using the appropriate command with max_num_segments set to 1

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/MY_INDEX/_optimize'
```

However in marvel I see the segment count as 10:

[Marvel Segment count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlyRw.png)

I'm guessing this is because my configuration of the cluster is 5 shards and 1 replica (5 + 5 * 1 = 10)? But I would like to confirm.

Thanks,

Ross

Comment: Shards are not segments - they are different things

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct. The `max_num_segments` parameter refers to the number of segments *per shard*. Lucene has no concept of shards or replicas...that's purely in Elasticsearch. So Elasticseach can only tell a given shard to be reduced to 1 Lucene segment.